# How to call a php variable in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to get the value of $jrowa['rate_score'] in PHP part as num3 in jQuery part. But the output is NaN for the alert in num3.

Here is my PHP code.

```
$jsqla = mysql_query("select id,name,rate_score,rate_number,video_image from products where genre='$genre' limit 0,5");

$arate_num = $jrowa['rate_number'];
    if($jrowa['rate_number'] > 0){ 
        $ratea = $jrowa['rate_score'] / $jrowa['rate_number']; 
        $ratea2 = $jrowa['rate_score'];
        $rateid = $jrowa['id'];
        $ratenum = $jrowa['rate_number'];
    }else{ 
        $ratea = $jrowa['rate_score']; 
        $ratea2 = $jrowa['rate_score'];
        $rateid = $jrowa['id'];
        $ratenum = $jrowa['rate_number'];
    }
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="col-sm-2 portfolio-item" style="width: 20%;">

     <input class="rating form-control input-star-rate" id="<?php echo $rateid; ?>" name="rating" value="<?php echo $ratea; ?>" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.3" data-size="xs" style="display: none; text-align: center;"/>

</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var $stars = $('.input-star-rate');

        $stars.bind('change', function() {
            var $this = $(this); //  assign $(this) to $this
            var ratingValue = $this.val();
            alert(ratingValue);
            var ratingValue2 = parseFloat(ratingValue);
            alert(ratingValue2);

            var ratingValuePrevious = parseFloat($(this).attr("value"));
            var ratingValuePrevious2 = parseFloat(ratingValuePrevious);
            alert(ratingValuePrevious2);

            var id = $this.attr("id");
            alert(id);

            var phpvalue = "<?php echo $jrowa['rate_score']; ?>";
            var num3 = parseInt(phpvalue, 10);
            alert(num3);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your Javascript *must* be inside the PHP file.

Comment: In **A** PHP file. You can also access a global variable in another PHP file.

Comment: @S.Pols dosent that require the file with global variable included in first file using require_once or other function

Comment: Depents how you defined it, if you use `define` you don't need to include the file, but yes it needs to be loaded once.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

html code:

```
<input class="rating form-control input-star-rate" id="<?php echo $rateid; ?>" name="rating" value="<?php echo $ratea; ?>" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.3" data-size="xs" style="display: none; text-align: center;" lats="<?php echo $rateid; ?>"/>
```

then in jquery:

```
var vals = $(this).attr('lats');// this will store your php variable value in jquery variable vals.
```